# Why does Gradle jar of jars result in duplicate libraries?

Tags: gradle, jar

Objective: Create Jar of Jars like Maven does.

I have this relevant snippet:

```
jar {
  into('lib') {
    from configurations.compile, configurations.runtime
  }
}
```

There must be something wrong with my conceptualization of what compile / runtime are. If I do this, I get duplicate copies of every library in the resulting jar. I'm really only trying to include everything that might go in and cover all the scopes. I want something I can easily rubber stamp for most ***jar*** situations as this is a very large build. I can get more specific for ***war*** files.

So... Why does this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html) says this about the runtime configuration:

> "**runtime**: The dependencies required by the production classes at runtime. By default, **also includes the compile time dependencies.**"

Just by copying from the runtime configuration, you would get all of the compile dependencies aswell. You are basically telling gradle to copy the same dependencies twice.

Comment: OIC, compile is a subset of runtime?

Comment: Is there a model for that anywhere? I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: @user447607 Yep compile is a subset of runtime. No model that I know of, but that documentation link I sent gives a pretty good idea.